# Visual Studio Code previous/next editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I looking for a quick way to switch the open editor between the files in order of use.

I found these two options

- Open Previous Editor
- Open Previous Recently Used Editor

Both of these does not open the editor I had open last but instead loops through the editors in the order they were originally opened. (or am I missing something?)

What I am looking for is something similar to Eclipse use of the back and forward arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cross-reference answer with a sample keybinding, see [How can I go back to previous tab opened in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077745/how-can-i-go-back-to-previous-tab-opened-in-vscode/59941711#59941711) and particularly https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md

v1.42 made some changes, it is now pretty easy to go back and forth through recently used editors even if they include split editors/other editor groups.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Alt + [1-9]` to switch to a specific tab or `Ctrl + Tab` to cycle between them.

Comment: Thanks, but still not what I am looking for. If you have a lot of files open, which I do, it does not really help.