# How can I go back to previous tab opened in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut to go back to previous tab opened (not previous position of cursor as `^-` does).
Could not find such action in docs.

Comment: for me, the case was "View: Open Previous Recently Used Editor" for anyone coming here with the same purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `View: Open Previous Editor` command.

You can also view the editor history using the `Open Previous Editor From History` command, and then pick the target editor you wish to open

Answer (score 2):

v1.42 introduces a bunch of new functionality - including the ability to cycle through recently used editors even when those editors are in different groups. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#navigate-most-recently-used-editors

> **Navigate most recently used editors**
>
> With this release, there is now a list of most recently used editors
>   across all editor groups. An editor is considered recently used when
>   it either opens as the active editor or becomes the new active editor
>   if already opened. Once an editor is closed, it is removed from this
>   list.
>
> One application of this list is the new `edt mru` picker that you can
>   open through the new View: Show All Editors By Most Recently Used
>   (`workbench.action.showAllEditorsByMostRecentlyUsed`) command:

[image: most recently used editors]

You can add keyboard shortcuts to quickly navigate in this picker without using the mouse. For example, below is a keybinding to so that kbstyle(Ctrl+Tab) and kbstyle(Ctrl+Shift+Tab) navigates across editors of all groups (instead of only within the active group as the default keybindings do):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor",
  "when": "!inEditorsPicker"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenLeastRecentlyUsedEditor",
  "when": "!inEditorsPicker"
}
```

> If you want to navigate the list without using a picker, there are new
>   commands:
>
> ```
> View: Open Next Recently Used Editor (`workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditor`)
>
> View: Open Previous Recently Used Editor (`workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor`)
> ```
>
> To differentiate which editor navigation commands work with a picker
>   and which ones don't, the behavior of some existing commands has
>   changed. Specifically, the Recently Used Editor in Group commands no
>   longer use a picker:
>
> ```
> View: Open Next Recently Used Editor in Group (`workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`)
>
> View: Open Previous Recently Used Editor in Group (`workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`)
> ```
>
> Use View: Quick Open Previous Recently Used Editor in Group
>   (`workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`) and
>
> View: Quick Open Least Recently Used Editor in Group
>   (`workbench.action.quickOpenLeastRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`) for
>   picker-based navigation.

---

So I made these keybindings to go backward and forward through most recently used editors (regardless of which editor group they may be in):

```
  {
    "key": "alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditor",
  },

 {
    "key": "shift+alt+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ctrl + Page Up` for previous tab and `Ctrl + Page Down` for next tab.

Comment: Fantastic! didn't know there's a native version. works on VS code too